# How use isolated scope action from one directive to another

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive like as follows

```
demoApp.directive('myButton', [function ($compile) {
    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        template: '<input type="button" value="Click" data-ng-click="click()" />',

        scope: { onSingleclick: '&singleclickFn' },

        link: function (scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {

            scope.click = function () {

                scope.onSingleclick();

            }
        }
    };

}]);
```

Controller Method:

```
$scope.singleClick = function () {

        alert('singleClick ' );

}
```

When I write :

`<my-button   singleclick-fn="singleClick()"></my-button>`

then it works perfectly.

The above code works fine.

Now I want to use another directive to wrapping the above directive. Like

```
demoApp.directive('myNewButton', [function ($compile) {
    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        scope: { singleclick: '&singleclickFn' },

        template: '<my-button singleclick-Fn="singleclickFn" />',

        link: function (scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {


        }
    };

}]);

<my-new-button   singleclick-fn="singleClick()"></my-new-button>
```

Now click method does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your template to:

`'<my-button singleclick-Fn="singleclick()" />'`

When you pass expressions with `&`, angular wraps them in a function and assigns that to the scope variable. So when you write `singleclick: '&singleclickFn'`, you would get this:

```
function singleclick(){
  $parse('singleClick()')
}
```

without the parentheses in `singleClick()` nothing would happen. You can also pass the function by reference by using `=` instead of `&` and removing the parentheses from the above. That would mean a reference to the actual function in the parent exists in the scope.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OcboiJ9tbpuE6NEYqC9s?p=preview)

Comment: Your are right. Your answer is correct. But My Actual problem is that my method has one parameter so how to pass parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the code. You dont need to bind the element to the click-event. Angular does that when you use ng-click.

```
app.directive('myButton', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="onSingleclick()" />',
    scope: { onSingleclick: '&singleclickFn' },
  };
}]);

app.directive('myNewButton', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { singleclick: '&singleclickFn' },
    template: '<my-button singleclick-fn="singleclick()" />',
  };
}]);
```

Edit:
Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hBWvvSXSZg4NGDuFmZLh?p=preview)

Comment: Your are right. Your answer is correct. But My Actual problem is that my method has one parameter so how to pass parameter?

Comment: It passes the parameter as you can see in the Plunker I have added in my edit.